# Website not opening on some browser

Tags: html, web, cpanel, http-status-code-500

I've a website www.makibs.com
It is an addon website on shared host with another website i.e 2 domain name on same hosting.

I'm using cpanel and added this domain and uploaded all website data into root directory/makibs.com folder.

Now when I try to load website it sometime loads on both chrome and firefox especially in incognito mode but sometime it wouldn't load and on mobile it load when entering prefix www without it its not loading on mobile also.

How can I fixed it?
anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be like Addon domain. When you are adding add on domain on your shared hosting you must have to specify www or not while adding add on domain name.

If you have write www up front in domain name then it will not run without www in mobile phones. The domain is working in chrome and mozila because desktop browsers fetch www automatically..

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! while adding domain I added just makibs.com as domain name.

Comment: then do not use www  while opening that in mobile browser.. 

i think it will work.. and feel free to mark as an answer..

thanks